# How can I revert an upgrade I had second thoughts about?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I went to upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04 and after hitting Y I had second thoughts as I don't want it to remove some software that isn't in the main release and I'd be happier staying on 22.04. The update was cancelled but now when I do `apt update` it is trying to upgrade to 23.04 again. Is there a way to tell the system that I want to stay on 22.04?

Comment: If you've applied any upgraded packages from 23.04 or *lunar*, I'd only go backwards using a non-destructive re-install (*you can cancel a release-upgrade during the download, but I'd not advise it once it started installing*). You mention *update was cancelled* which is unusual wording to me, as the *release-upgrade* process is different to the normal upgrading of packages, so it'll be helpful if you're specific - but Ubuntu releases are intended to go to newer release only; as users have backups they can restore if they need to go backwards for a reason (*it's why users create them*).

Comment: I cancelled it during the download process no packages were installed. It was a `release-upgrade` - how do I do a non-destructive re-install?

Comment: If you cancelled whilst it was still downloading packages, you should not need to do a re-install; just revert your sources so they use *jammy* (22.04) not *lunar* (23.04).  I don't have a system handy that was recently *release-upgraded* to check what was done, but I'm sure a copy of the *untouched* sources files are where expected (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) just with a different name (*I've done that myself*), OR you can just edit the file & return the codename to what it was (ie. *jammy*).  You didn't mention Server/Desktop, and I'm mostly desktop user, but I'd expect the same for both.

Comment: That did the trick it was there under `sources.list.curtain.old` thank you.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer then, explaining what you did. Key to me was you were still downloading, thus no actual changes had occurred (*downloading can take awhile if you have loads of packages*)...  I couldn't recall what it was called (*the old file*) thus why I only commented. You can mention me, or not in answer; but you'll gain *rep*, and may help other users in the future. Well done for solving it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that happens into the same issue, I found `sources.list.curtain.old` in `/etc/apt/` - I renamed the new one to .new and renamed the old one and it's not trying to update anymore.

Thanks to guiverc for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You commented that you interrupted during download, so you should first remove the downloaded files to free up space using `sudo apt clean`.

Now you should set the release channel back to LTS. Open the Update Manager app, and click on settings after it loaded. Now switch to the "Updates" tab, and change "Notify on new Ubuntu update" to "Long-term supported release", and close it. If it asks you to update the source when clicked Close, click on "Update". Here is a picture about it (the language is not English for me, but the buttons are placed in the same places, so you can compare it with yours and I also use the Orchis theme, so the buttons may look different for you):
[image: Settings]